# Failing to load libGL.so.1 after installing bumblebee

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl, optimus

I am running Linux Mint 15 64bit. My laptop has a Geforce 640M Optimus card, so I installed bumblebee according to the [installation instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) (Basic Setup).
Using optirun to run programs (e.g. Steam) works as intended. However, certain programs like Skype, now show

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when not run with optirun. I do not want Skype to run on the dedicated card, so this is an issue. The following libGL.so.1 files are found on my system:

```
/usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

If I run

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype
```

all works well.

This is the output for **update-alternatives --query i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf**:

```
Name: i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
Link: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf
Slaves:
 i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf
Value: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf

Alternative: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
Priority: 500
Slaves:
 i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules

Alternative: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf
Priority: 9701
Slaves:
```

I tried updating the alternatives to the mesa one, but this does not fix the problem.

What do I have to do to get GL support without optirun?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: But if You'll add `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1` to `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` does it work after a reboot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the fix, someone else posted it on askubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/125040/after-installation-of-bumblebee-i386-opengl-apps-stopped-working

If you haven't yet installed bumblebee, simply install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` before you install bumblebee and you should be fine.

If you have already installed bumblebee, install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and then reinstall `bumblebee-nvidia`. It worked for me! (I used `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove bumblebee-nvidia`, then just reinstalled it.)